# What does ! in the %retab! mean?

Tags: bash, retab

`%retab!` can replace all  characters with spaces.

The `%` in command `%retab!` means the whole lines in the current file.

`help retab` show something such as:

```
With !, Vim also replaces strings of only normal spaces with tabs where appropriate.
```

The `!` in `!ls` means to execute a shell command behind it.
`help !` show contents on filter.

What does `!` in the `%retab!` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing `!` in Vim commands provides an alternative version of the command with slightly different behavior. It differs for every command.

For `retab` with `noexpandtab` set, the `retab` command does not convert pure space identation into tabs whereas the `retab!` command does convert them.

For example:

```
if True:
....print("hello")
->  print("world")
....if True:
->  ....print("!")
```

Using `retab` the non homogeneous indentation is translated using leading tabs and spaces but not the pure space one:

```
if True:
....print("hello")
->  print("world")
....if True:
->  ->print("!")
```

Using `retab!` all the indentation is translated using leading tabs and spaces:

```
if True:
->  print("hello")
->  print("world")
->  if True:
->  ->  print("!")
```

Remark: `retab!` converts also pure spaces that are not at the start of the line into tabs.

```
bo..bo
```

will be converted into:

```
bo->bo
```

Comment: Thanks Rich I'm not native I have to improve ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If `!` stands *after* command it works as command parameter (boolean flag). Absolutely no relation with `!` command.

What the flag does or if it is even allowed here that depends on a particular command.

When you don't know something you read the relevant help topic and then do some experimenting to check if you got it right. Just create new file, enter some text with many consecutive spaces and/or tabs and try to retab it this way or that.

So "the exclamation mark" after `retab` allows "to process" also blank sequences that have no tabs at all but only plain spaces. Like was promised by the help.

Of course, if you have `expandtab` on that will do nothing anyway (how many spaces you expect to get out of ten spaces?)

Comment: In general, that exclamation suffix (like in `q!`) means an advanced usage and/or a call to caution (it remind me `/!\\` sign) because it will go further than what novice users will expect.

Comment: @gildux Rather alternative/non-default functionality. Because, well, it is not by default. However, it all depends on a specific command.